# HDF5 Installation Error in the latest Ubuntu 18.04LTS with Intel Compilers

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, hadoop, icc

While I used HDF5 library without any problem with Ubuntu version 16.04 LTS, after I upgraded Ubuntu to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I have trouble in installing HDF5 with Intel Fortran and C Compilers.

I successfully installed HDF5 with gcc and gfortran.

But, I need to install HDF5 with Intel Fortran and C Compilers to further usage of scientific computation codes which are only compatible with Intel compilers.

I installed `szip-2.1.1` and `zlib-1.2.11` in the path of `$HOME/LIB` using

- ifort version 18.0.2
- icc version 18.0.2 (gcc version 7.0.0 compatibility)
- icpc version 18.0.2 (gcc version 7.0.0 compatibility)
  (parallel_studio_xe_2018_update2_cluster_edition, compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.199)

with these flags in bash profile

```
export CC=icc
export CXX=icpc
export FC=ifort
export F9X=ifort
export CFLAGS='-O3 -xHost -ip'
export CXXFLAGS='-O3 -xHost -ip'
export FCFLAGS='-O3 -xHost -ip'
```

and tried to install

```
hdf5-1.10.2
```

with following configuration

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/LIB --with-zlib=$HOME/LIB --with-szip=$HOME/LIB LD_LIBRARY_PATH=-L/home/scyook/LIB/lib CPPFLAGS=-I/home/scyook/LIB/include --enable-fortran --enable-cxx --enable-fortran2003
```

However next error message appears.

```
checking size of size_t... configure: error: in `/home/scyook/LIB/hdf5-1.10.2`:
configure: error: cannot compute sizeof (size_t)
```

these are the last parts of config.log

```
.  #define SIZEOF_INT32_T 0   
.  #define SIZEOF_UINT32_T 0    
.  #define SIZEOF_INT_LEAST32_T 0    
.  #define SIZEOF_UINT_LEAST32_T 0    
.  #define SIZEOF_INT_FAST32_T 0    
.  #define SIZEOF_UINT_FAST32_T 0    
.  #define SIZEOF_INT64_T 0    
.  #define SIZEOF_UINT64_T 0    
.  #define SIZEOF_INT_LEAST64_T 0    
.  #define SIZEOF_UINT_LEAST64_T 0    
.  #define SIZEOF_INT_FAST64_T 0    
.  #define SIZEOF_UINT_FAST64_T 0
configure: exit 77
```

Could I get help for resolving this issue?

Comment: I guess you could use the available patches http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/h/hdf5/hdf5_1.10.2+repack-1~exp1.debian.tar.xz → `debian/patches/*`